# create new git repository starting at specified commit in existing repository

Tags: git, repository

I've recently converted a commercially licensed code to a BSD license by replacing sections of the code that had conflicting license agreements.  I did all of this in a private bitbucket git repository.  Now I am ready to release it to the public in a github public git repository.    So, I need to create the new repository by forgetting the early repository history (which contains proprietary code).  In other words, I have

```
M1 - M2 - ... - Mgood - Mgood+1 - ... - Mtip
                                   \ B1 - B2 - ... - Btip
```

and what I want in the new repo is:

```
Mgood - Mgood+1 - ... - Mtip                   
                   \ B1 - B2 - ... - Btip
```

with the repository history (comments, changes, etc.) prior to Mgood totally forgotten.  Being fairly new to git, this sounds easy but I haven't yet figured out the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using `git rebase -i`

You'd just need to squash the olds commits into one:

```
s M1
s M2
p Mgood+1
p Mtip
```

So here you mark `M1` and `M2` to be squash (`s` flag) and you keep all other commits (`c` flag)

But if you have a pretty large history, this may be a lot of manual works.

Comment: It is a small to moderate history, meaning hundreds (not thousands) of commits.  I will give this a try.  Thanks for your prompt reply.